# How can I check if a user is already logged in? (everyauth, node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, everyauth

Up until now I've been using client-side auth. I just set up server-side everyauth and it is working great but how can I do something like `FB.getLoginStatus`(what I did client-side) when the page loads?

If the user is already logged in I dont want to put them through the process again.

Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth)

> everyauth also provides convenience methods on the ServerRequest
>   instance req. From any scope that has access to req, you get the
>   following convenience getters and methods:
>
> `req.loggedIn` - a Boolean getter that tells you if the request is by a
>   logged in user
>
> `req.user` - the User document associated with the
>   session
>
> `req.logout()` - clears the sesion of your auth data

Within Express Views:

> If you are using express, everyauth comes with some useful dynamic
>   helpers. To enable them:
>
> ```
> var express = require('express')
> , everyauth = require('everyauth') 
> , app = express.createServer();
> everyauth.helpExpress(app);
> ```
>
> Then, from within your views, you will
>   have access to the following helpers methods attached to the helper,
>   everyauth:
>
> ```
> everyauth.loggedIn
> ```

Comment: What would this look like if we're not using express?

Comment: Are you using Connect? Everyauth is designed to be used with Connect & Express. The first example should still work.

Comment: `app.get('/', function(req, res){
  if(req.loggedIn){res.send('you're logged in')}
});`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this on node.js:

```
var userlogin = function () {
       var req = this.request
          ,res = this.response
          ,login = req.body
          ,username = login.username
          ,password = login.password;

      if(username === 'tester' && password === '12345'){
         req.session.user_id = xxxxxx;
         res.redirect('/');
      }else{
        res.redirect('/login');
      }

    }
    var checkAuth = function(fn_auth, fn_unauth){
      var req = this.request
          ,res = this.response
          ,unauthCallback;

      if(req.session.user_id){
        fn_auth(); //execute fn_auth if user is logged in. callback can be set to redirect to root path '/'
      }else{
          fn_unauth(); //execute fn_unauth calback which bring user to login path '/login'
        } 
      }
    }
```

Basically just redirect when the user is already logged in. Hope that helps?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Jade template, user's login status can be checked by following code inside a .jade file, for example - home.jade

```
if (!everyauth.loggedIn) // <-----
    a(href="/your_url_here/") log in with facebook
else
    p Welcome <username>
```