# Concerns in using everyauth

Tags: javascript, facebook, everyauth

I am having serious trouble in using everyauth. All I need is facebook login. For that I am trying to use the example of everyauth. Once I do facebook authentication, how can I check in every page if the user is logged in or not/ get his facebook information. What I have done is

```
var exp = require('express');
var app = exp.createServer();

var conf = require('/Users/lakeshkansakar/clicker/node_modules/everyauth/example/conf')
var everyauth = require('everyauth');

everyauth.debug = true;

var usersById = {};
var nextUserId = 0;

function addUser (source, sourceUser) {
  var user;
  user = usersById[++nextUserId] = {id: nextUserId};
  user[source] = sourceUser;
  return user;
}

var usersByFbId = {};
var usersByTwitId = {};

everyauth.everymodule
  .findUserById( function (id, callback) {
    callback(null, usersById[id]);
  });

everyauth
  .facebook
    .appId(conf.fb.appId)
    .appSecret(conf.fb.appSecret)
    .findOrCreateUser( function (session, accessToken, accessTokenExtra, fbUserMetadata) {
      return usersByFbId[fbUserMetadata.id] || (usersByFbId[fbUserMetadata.id] = addUser('facebook', fbUserMetadata));;
    })
    .redirectPath('/');

everyauth
  .twitter
    .consumerKey(conf.twit.consumerKey)
    .consumerSecret(conf.twit.consumerSecret)
    .findOrCreateUser( function (sess, accessToken, accessSecret, twitUser) {
      return usersByTwitId[twitUser.id] || (usersByTwitId[twitUser.id] = addUser('twitter', twitUser));;
    })
    .redirectPath('/');
```

In every get request, I then tried to check if everyauth.loggedIn is true or not. However, everyauth.loggedIn is shown to be undefined. Why is it so? How to check if the user has logged in using facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this will help or not, but I researched both EveryAuth and Passport, and was able to implement Passport for Facebook and Google very quickly.  It looks like a much cleaner implementation of authentication.

http://passportjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Once you are logged In, you will be redirected to "/" as mentioned in `.redirectPath('/');`.

In the routes for "/", you can check for `everyauth.loggedIn`.

You can see more details here.. [How can I check if a user is already logged in? (everyauth, node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029217/how-can-i-check-if-a-user-is-already-logged-in-everyauth-node-js)

Hope this helps!